# Calling Rest API from mapreduce (reducer)

Tags: rest, post, mapreduce

Do you see any problem of calling a REST POST API from mapreduce reducer method?
The Api is low latency :20 milliseconds per call/key.
There is time-out if a call takes more than defined.
The API output is used by further logic in the reducer.

Thank you in advance
Vladek

Comment: 20ms per key means you can only get throughput of 50 records per second per reducer. I'm not sure how many records you have but if you're using MapReduce then your data size is large enough that that's probably too slow.